# Как в .net создать несколько COM-объектов различных версий?

Tags: .net, com

Требуется создать модуль, который будет подключаться через COM к 1С. Сама по себе задача элементарная, но загвоздка в том, что 1С могут быть различных версий.
Как обычно решается эта задача - в приложении просто пишется создается COM-объекта по его имени "v82.ComConnector", а пользователь должен перед запуском зарегистрировать dll нужной версии через regsvr32. Но в моей ситуации нужно из приложения обращаться сразу к различным версиям серверов 1С.

Собственно вопрос - как динамически в .net подгрузить dll нужной версии 1С в память и затем создать по ней COM-объект?

В интернете находил варианты с подгрузкой через Assembly.LoadFrom( или через LoadLibrary от kernel32.dll, но не могу заставить эти варианты работать..

Заранее спасибо за помощь!

Comment: не совсем понятно какую dll и откуда вы будете брать и грузить в память (пользователь будет задавать или сами будете искать по реестру?). зачем нужна регистрация компонент через regsvr, ибо если 1с стоит, то и comconnector уже зарегистрирован? и в чем проблема прописать названия ком-объектов в приложении?  
опишите задачу поподробнее.

Comment: Проблема в том, что серверов может быть несколько, и версии у всех разные. А на одной машине может быть зарегистрирована только одна версия в одно время.
Мне нужно из одного приложения подключится к списку серверов с разными версиями. Это инструмент для администратора, поэтому пути к нужным версиям dll пользователь может задать вручную.
На самом деле это одна из "вечных" проблем 1С, которую производитель не хочет решать :).

Comment: видимо придется отрегистрировать одну версию, зарегистрировать другую, поработать и снова по кругу.

Comment: @Aleksey Bochkov, да, придется вручную регистрировать:

* OleInitialize
* Функции LoadLibrary для загрузки библиотеки DLL
* Функция DllRegisterServer или DllUnregisterServer
* FreeLibrary
* OleUninitialize
  
см. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/207132/ru  

Впрочем, вы можете монитором реестра проследить что меняется в реестре при регистрации, вероятно там ключ-два прописываются всего, можете их менять перед созданием объекта, но это все какое-то шаманство.  

имхо, администратору стоит заняться актуализацией версий серверов в пределах минорной версии: 8.0, 8.1, 8.2, 8.3.

Comment: А почему не [Regfree COM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_Object_Model#Registration-free_COM)?

---
Вот ещё по теме: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10888/SafeCOMWrapper-Managed-Disposable-Strongly-Typed-s

Comment: @Yura Ivanov, попробовал этот вариант. Работает, но проблема с кэшем.
Если последовательно регистрировать несколько разных версий и создавать объекты, то первая регистрация отрабатывает нормально, а последующие игнорируются (COM-объекты создаются от первой зарегистрированной DLL).
Такая же проблема если напрямую править реестр.

Comment: @VladD, да, видел ссылки на это, но пока мозгов не хватает, чтобы прикрутить это :)
Там в примерах везде ссылка на одну конкретную DLL. А если их 3 и с одинаковыми CLSID?